# ¿Cómo acceder a los datos de sql LocalDB desde Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mvc

para el desarrollo de una aplicación MVC estoy usando una sql LocalDB para almacenar de forma momentánea los datos que recojo de un servidor y mostrarlos en una lista.

Puedo pasar los datos de esa DB del controlador a la vista y mostrarlos con HTML en una tabla, la cosa es que quería crear la tabla desde una función JavaScript en vez desde HTML directamente para así tener más libertad a la hora de personalizarla.

El problema es a la hora de acceder a los datos de la LocalDB desde JavaScript, no sé por cuál de las opciones que voy a explicar a continuación hacerlo,  y la verdad que tampoco sé si existe alguna manera  mejor de hacerlo.

Opción 1) Mediante petición ajax directamente desde JavaScript que me invoque al controlador que me devuelve la lista con los datos de la Local DB.

Opción 2) Obtener los datos mediante una Viewbag que pase del controlador a la vista, y lo incluya como parámetro de la función Javascript cuando la invoco en la función onclick de un botón, por ejemplo.

Agradezco por antelación vuestra ayuda y vuestro tiempo.

Un saludo

Comment: Debes mostrar algo mas de informacion para que sea mas fácil ayudarte. Muestra algo de código, que has intentado y como, que error recibes etc. Te invito a ver el enlace sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente lo que tienes que realizar es una petición al controlador para que este te retorne un `JSON` con los datos de tu base de datos.

Este ejemplo realizar una petición a una función del controlador y al obtener el `JSON` lo lista en una tabla.

Código `AJAX`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var academyModal = $('#data-academy-modal');
    var titleDataAcademyModal = $('#titleDataAcademyModal');
    var formAcademyData = $('#formAcademyData');
    var academiesTableBody = $('#academiesTable tbody');
    var departmentSelect = $('#departmentSelect');
    var presidentSelect = $('#presidentSelect');

    var dt = $('#academiesTable').DataTable({
        'ajax': "<?echo(base_url('index.php/Admin/getAcademiesJson'))?>",
        bAutoWidth: false,
        "columns": [
            {"data": "academy_name"},
            {"data": "department_name"},
            {"data": "academy_president"},
            {
                render: function (data, type, rowData, meta) {
                    return '<a class="btnEdit" data-toggle="modal" data-academy="' + rowData.academy_id + '">' + '<i class="fa fa-pencil text-info m-r-10"></i>' + '</a>' +
                        '<a class="btnDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal" data-academy="' + rowData.academy_id + '">' + '<i class="fa fa-close text-danger"></i>' + '</a>'
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Código `Controlador`:

```
public function getAcademiesJson()
{
    $data['data'] = $this->Admin_model->getAcademies();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Código `Modelo`:

```
public function getAcademies()
{
    $this->db->select('a.academy_id, a.id_department, a.id_academy_president, a.academy_name, d.department_name, CONCAT(u.user_name, " ", u.user_parental_surname) AS academy_president');
    $this->db->from('academies a');
    $this->db->join('departments d', 'a.id_department = d.department_id');
    $this->db->join('users u', 'a.id_academy_president = u.user_id');

    $aResult = $this->db->get();

    if(!$aResult->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return $aResult->result_array();
}
```

La invocación desde un botón la puedes realizar de una forma sencilla.